# How to choose starting Activity based on condition in Android

Tags: android

How can I dynamically select the **starting Activity** of my application?

Take for example this scenario: the first time the user opens the app, he will see the **AuthenticationActivity**, after that, he will see the **MainActivity**. If he logs out, he will see the **AuthenticationActivity** again.

I **don't** want to use a **splash screen** or something similar and I'm wondering if there is any way of doing this.

I was thinking of checking if there are any accounts in the **onCreate** method of the **MainActivity**, before calling **setContentView**, and display the **AuthenticationActivity** if not, but it doesn't feel ok to me.

Comment: your solution works. alternatively, you can start the AuthenticationActivity first, and simply redirect to he mainactivity if there are accounts. If you finish and start a new activity in the `onCreate`, it is not visible to the user.

Comment: you can create a base activity and inherit main and authenticate activity from it, then in onCreate method in base actvity, check account and show the proper activity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public class NavigatorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent;

        if (isAuthenticated) {
            intent = new Intent(NavigatorActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(NavigatorActivity.this,
                AuthenticationActivity.class);
        }

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And launch your app with this `NavigatorActivity`.

Comment: Do I have to extend NavigatorActivity with Activity class or can it also be AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @Ady96 It doesn't matter, it can be AppCompatActivity as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set MainActivity the parent of LoginActivity, set LoginActivity as Main/Launcher and call finish() if already logged in.

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Instead of getting back to the last activity, it launch the parent one.

Comment: I am doing it, but the MainActivity is not being launched, is there any other step you forgot to mention?